# Can I use a 5GHz USB Network Stick on a 2.4GHz-only Laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a laptop whose wifi card can only access my home router's 2.4GHz network.  The router also provides a 5GHz network.  Can I get a USB network stick that can access the 5GHz network, attach it to my laptop, and use the 5GHz network?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: probably.

Longer answer:

This depends on whether on not your computer supports the USB wifi adapter. Normally a USB wifi adapter has drivers provided with it (via a CD), can have the drivers installed via Windows Update or possibly have vanilla drivers which come baked in with Windows.

Just make sure the Wifi card is compatible with your version of Windows and you'll likely be set!